# I am writing a bot for telegrams so as not to repeat myself, I use the function and get an error name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I have a code like this, the function avoids eternal repetitions. But when I try to use it I get an error: name 'keyF' is not defined
How can this be fixed?

```
def comand(a,b):
    keyF = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btnOne = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="BACK PAGE", callback_data=a)
    btnTwo = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="NEXT PAGE", callback_data=b)
    keyF.add(btnOne, btnTwo)

@by.callback_query_handler(text="TWO1")
async def send_random_value(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    comand("TWO2", "TWOBACK1")
    await call.message.answer(lists[1], reply_markup=keyF)
```

Comment: Did you mean to return `keyF` from the `command()` function?

Comment: @quamrana Yes, but it didn't help me

Comment: It should.  What I meant was use `return keyF` in your function and then `keyF = command("TWO2",  ...`. This will bring the value into your async function.